# How to get a program's installation path using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've tried to use Get-ChildItem to get installed program property information and it does provide some of the information I require but the Installed Location/path is usually blank.  Given a program's name/displayname, is there a way reliable way to get the installation path of a Windows Server program (remote to other servers) using Powershell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why -1, the question is sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

Using Registry:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | 
% { Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath } | Select DisplayName,InstallLocation
```

Using WMI:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter 'Name like "%Microsoft Office%"' | 
Select Caption,InstallLocation
```

For Remoting, Through registry it's totally different story, with WMI just add the `-ComputerName` Parameter (and make sure you have permissions)

Comment: Thanks Avshalom but they don't solve the problem of programs that don't have the InstallLocation property defined.  Unfortunately, most programs don't have InstallLocation defined.   Need another method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use these `cmdlets` to get the paths:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | % { Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath } | Select DisplayName,InstallLocation | Sort-Object Displayname -Descending

Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | % { Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath } | Select DisplayName,InstallLocation | Sort-Object Displayname -Descending
```

These show different programs and their locations.